# In general with Active Directory, what do most companies use as unique identifier for people?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to build a database that stores Active-Directory entries for users/employees.

1. Is it safe to assume to query on: `(objectClass=person)`
2. What attribute should I store as a unique identifier that isn't the DN? e.g. should I use `mail` or `uid`

Also when an employee gets de-activated is there a new attribute that gets added or are they simply removed entirely from AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asked by you seems to be somewhat opinion based, but I'll talk it from the context of general options available in AD and the usual practices followed.

> 1. Is it safe to assume to query on: (objectClass=person)?

All the users created do come under the category of `(objectClass=person)`. But, then if you create a generic-user for having file-share access on a system (through ADUC(dsa.msc) / powershell / C#, etc) which would not be an employee, then in this case it would violate your search condition despite being a person class. I can think of so many other scenarios where it would be impossible to avoid generic-users creation (which would again lie in person objectClass), at least from the viewpoint of mid-sized company and above.

Hence, in such cases it is better to follow a naming convention in your environment to avoid any such confusion. One sample example could be, say set the UPN/sAMAccountName for non-employee users to start from genXXXX, and you'd be easily able to search all employee users henceforth.

> 2. What attribute should I store as a unique identifier that isn't the DN? e.g. should I use mail or uid?

There are unique identifiers already available in AD like `objectGUID` and `objectSid`. In a domain, the sAMAccountName/UPN values are also unique. But, you cannot rely on that for forest-level search.

objectSid for a user can change when the user is migrated to another domain, but **objectGUID** never changes. You can read more about [SIDs versus GUIDs here](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/SIDs-versus-GUIDs).

> Also when an employee gets de-activated is there a new attribute that
>   gets added or are they simply removed entirely from AD?

There is no automatic trigger at AD side. There is an attribute called `lastLogontimeStamp` which helps keep a track when a user or computer account has logged onto the domain (not the live scenario, but recent one - depending on if it keeps updating properly).

Someone has to manually disable/delete the account if an employee/user leaves the organisation. There are process setup in companies to deal with this scenario where the Access Management solutions are linked with AD modules, and take care of the entry and exit of the users and perform relevant action in AD.

---

Hope it gives a rough idea of management for the queries raised by you.

Comment: holy cow, this is awesome.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, thanks for your feedback! Please do upvote the answer as well, if you haven't. Good Luck @TimNuwin!